# Generate large amounts of data with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Trying to generate a lot of data with `numpy` without success. To be clear is not the libraries fault - I just do not have enough memory in my computer ~ 32gb of ram.

Is there a better way to do this such as simultaneously save on disk rather than in memory?

Here is the working code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def main():
    
    (images, labels), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path="mnist.npz")
    rescaled_images = np.reshape(images, (images.shape[0], images.shape[1] * images.shape[1]))

    indices = np.where(labels==0)
    zero_images = np.take(rescaled_images, indices, axis=0)[0]
    x0 = np.array(zero_images).astype(np.float32)

    length = zero_images.shape[1]
    ones = np.ones(length)
    
    steps = 1000000 # <--- problem even with one step
    mu = -2.0
    sigma = 1.5
    dt = 0.01

    data = []
    for image in x0:
        diff_imgs = [image]
        x = x0
        for i in range(steps):
            x = x + mu * ones * dt + sigma * ones * np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(length)
            diff_imgs.append(x)
        data.append(diff_imgs)

    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving data to disk, can give you some more headroom. But when you dont need all the data simultaneously, or a saved history of the data generated, you can get away with just creating a recipe of how to create the data.

This idea can be achieved by creating a generator using the `yield` instead of return (for more generator information see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)). Hence you create the recipe for the logic and then just call the `next` function of that object every time you need more data.

An example from your case:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import 

# Constants:
MU = -2.0
SIGMA = 1.5
DT = 0.01


def img_add_noise(image):
    return(image+MU*DT+SIGMA*np.sqrt(DT)*np.random.randn(len(image)))

def data_add_noise(images, steps):
    for image in images:
        batch_data = [image]
        for i in range(steps):
            batch_data.append(img_add_noise(batch_data[-1]))
        yield(np.stack(batch_data).astype(np.float32))


def main():
    (images, labels), (_,_) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path="mnist.npz")
    rescaled_images = images.reshape(len(images), -1)
    zero_images = np.take(rescaled_images, indices, axis=0)[0]
    data = data_add_noise(zero_images, 10)
    sample_data = next(data)
    print(sample_data.shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way you can also make a function that can generate an infinite amount of data by change the for loop of `for image in images` in `data_add_noise` function to

```
counter = 0
while True:
    image = images[counter%len(images)]
    counter += 1
```

If the generated data is being used for training tensorflow models, have a look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence), how to use `sequence` to achieve that.